# Embed a Paypal pay button onto a neighborhood website

Tags: paypal

I have the following link :
https://paypal.me/brandywinehillsde which will take a person directly to the correct place to donate to our neighborhood association.

If I edit the http://www.neighborhoodlink.com/xxx to add this, I need to know the actual HTML code to paste into this section to get a nice clickable button rather than a simple text line showing the address.
I'm not a web person!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nice clickable button, you can generate HTML buttons at https://www.paypal.com/buttons .  The classic Buy Now button can be made to say Pay Now, or you may prefer the newer smart button.